# How to estimate a VAR with simultaneous interactions?

Tags: vector-autoregression, simultaneous-equation

I want to analyse the interactions between the following data:

- tourist arrivals (my variable of interest)
- income of the tourists
- accomodation capacity (in number of rooms in hotels)
- a confidence index (an index asking "how do you evaluate your current financial situation?")

My hypothesis is that tourist arrivals are mostly influenced by the confidence of tourists in the short term, and by accomocation capacity in the long run. So, I estimated a VAR with these variables (monthly data), and want to make this analysis via impulse response fonctions. My expectation is that the confidence has a high impact on arrivals in the first months and then fades away. The accomodation capacity on the other hand, has a lasting impact.

**But, the problem is that I need to see the simulataneous interactions between variables; how the accomodation capacity and confidence affect tourist arrivals in the same month. How can I do that?**

I use Eviews, which does not allow to make a lag=0 VAR.

Is this normal? If so, why can't I make a lag=0 VAR?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See structural VAR (SVAR) modelling, e.g. in

- Lütkepohl ["New Introduction to Multiple Time Series Analysis"](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540401728) (2005), Chapter 9;
- Pfaff ["Analysis of Integrated and Cointegrated Time Series with R"](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387759661) (2008), Section 2.3; or
- the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/vignettes/vars.pdf) of "vars" package in R, Section 2.2;

among other sources. SVAR is a form of VAR that allows for contemporaneous relations between variables. Actually, to estimate a SVAR you first turn it into a corresponding VAR representation and then turn the results back into the SVAR representation. The latter step can be done under special conditions related to the concept of *identification*.

If your series happen to be integrated and cointegrated, a special form of SVAR, namely, a structural VECM (SVECM) could be the relevant model. It is also covered in the sources cited above.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, you got me right, it's not the simultaneous shocks but the simultaneous interactions in the equations that I need. So you suggest that I use structural VARs... do you mean VECM? I don't use R, but Eviews. But when I choose the VEC option, even then, I have the following long run equation:

 
Cointegrating Eq:  CointEq1
 
LOG(N_SA(-1))  1.000000
 
LOG(COF_SA(-1)) -1.369492
                         (2.50500)
                         [-0.54670]

Comment: @SivaKg, then you can edit the title. No, SVAR is not VECM. If you took a quick look at the sources I refer to, you would notice the difference. Despite the sources including R codes, the basic idea applies more widely. If you wish, you can just ignore the R examples.